# Where does Leibniz discuss the value of variety?

Tags: reference-request, leibniz

I believe that I remember that Leibniz put strong value upon the varieties found in the world, e.g. as between human cultures and in nature. What are some good references for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topic of varieties is discussed in the Internet Encyclopedia of Philosophy article, “[Gottfried Leibniz: Metaphysics”, section 5, “Necessary Being”, and section 6, “Problems of Sin, Freedom, and Evil](https://iep.utm.edu/leib-met/#H6)”.

> To try to understand further this notion of perfection, Leibniz explores several concepts in various writings: notions of the best, the beautiful, the simply [compossible](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compossibility), greatest variety or the greatest quantity of essence. The last of these is the explanation he continually comes back to: perfection simply means the greatest quantity of essence, which is to say the greatest richness and variety in each substance, compatible with the least number of basic laws, so as to exhibit an intelligible order that is “distinctly thinkable” in the variety (see “A Resume of Metaphysics;” there is a relationship to the Medieval, and particularly Augustine, notion of plenitude). Leibniz seems to understand this principle as simply self-evident. It certainly seems to be a big jump to the aesthetic, moral, and wise God from the ontological conception of God deduced above. However, Leibniz may have a point in arguing that it would be absurd in some sense for an infinite being to choose anything other than an infinitely rich and thus perfect universe. He also finds this aesthetic observed throughout nature: natural forms tend towards a maximum of variety compatible with orderliness. Nevertheless, contemporary philosophers generally find Leibniz’s conclusion here to not strictly follow from the previous considerations.
>
> For Leibniz, this forms a proof for the existence of God (see Monadology §§37-39 and “A Specimen of Discoveries”). In fact, it is a version of the third of the cosmological arguments given by St. Thomas Aquinas, and subject to many of the same difficulties. One might, for example, object in a Kantian vein that the concept of explanation, rightly demanded of all individual contingent beings, is applied beyond its proper sphere in demanding an explanation of the totality of contingent beings. But Leibniz might well counter that this objection assumes a whole theory of the “proper spheres” of concepts.